# How to return string from function to Ruby with CGO

Tags: ruby, go, ffi, cgo

I have a function in Go:

```
func login(user *C.char) *C.char {
    cstr := C.CString("Hello World")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cstr))
    return cstr 
}
```

My ruby code as below

```
module GoLib
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib './golib.so'

  attach_function :login, [:string], :string
end

GoLib.login("User1") #=> "p\x9A\xA0\xDB\x16V"
```

it does not return as ruby string. How to I fix this?

Comment: `cstr` is already free'd after `login()`. Try removing `defer C.free()` and manage the memory in Ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `cstr` gets free'd after control has been passed to Ruby. Here is a workaround where you explicitly manage the pointer in Ruby.

```
package main

// #include <stdlib.h>
import "C"
import "unsafe"

//export login
func login(user *C.char) *C.char {
    return C.CString("Hello from Go")
}

//export logout
func logout(c *C.char) {
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(c))
}

func main() {}
```

In Ruby:

```
require 'ffi'

module GoLib
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib './so.so'

  attach_function :login, [:string], :strptr
  attach_function :logout, [:pointer], :void
end

s, p = GoLib.login("User1")
puts s
p = FFI::AutoPointer.new(p, GoLib.method(:logout))
```

Note the use of `strptr` as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Pointers#fresh-strings)